# How do i find all the truecrypt encrypted container files through terminal?

Tags: command-line, truecrypt

I have created many encrypted container files through truecrypt and stored it in different locations on my Hard drive. Now i want to list those.

How do I list all encrypted container files along with their paths through terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find -name '*.tc'` will show you all the files that have the `.tc` extension but as with anything, extensions are only there for our benefit and it's possible (even likely if you're being secretive) that a TrueCrypt container won't have an extension (or it might have another).

There is [a project called TCHunt](https://github.com/stephenjudge/TCHunt) which semi-exhasively checks that it's not another sort of file (and looks for random data patterns). It should compile and give you an opportunity to do a full scan... But it's probably going to take a while to run and it's almost certainly going to flag files that aren't containers.

It's a bit of a pain to build because it needs so many dependencies but it can be done:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libboost-{filesystem,system,date-time,thread}-dev libxinerama-dev libfltk1.3-dev
git clone https://github.com/stephenjudge/TCHunt.git
cd TCHunt
g++ -Os  `fltk-config --cxxflags` TCHunt.cpp `fltk-config --ldstaticflags` -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -otchunt
```

And then you can run `./tchunt` — tell it where to search and it should run off and look for files it things are containers.

Comment: sorry my encrypted container doesn't have any `.tc` extension.

Comment: Didn't you see the second half of the answer?